# Specify options for a filter in ruby HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby, filter, haml, indentation

Is there any way to add options (HTML attributes) to HAML filters?

I wanted to do something like this :

```
:javascript{:'data-turbolinks-eval' => 'false', :foo => 'bar'}
  if(someCondition){
    doSomething();
  }
```

And the result would be :

```
<script 'data-turbolinks-eval'='false' 'foo'='bar'>
  if(someCondition){
    doSomething();
  }
</script>
```

The closest I could get is :

```
%script{:'data-turbolinks-eval' => 'false', :foo => 'bar'}
  if(someCondition){
  doSomething();
  }
```

The drawback is that you can't indent your JS in HAML unless you're using the :javascript filter. It's ok for a few lines, but it can get messy quickly.

I'm well aware that in most cases if you end up with a complex script in a HAML template, it means you're doing something wrong and that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to pass extra attributes to the `:javascript` filter like this. You could however use a `:plain` filter along with a normal `script` tag to allow indenting your javascript code:

```haml
%script{:'data-turbolinks-eval' => 'false', :foo => 'bar'}
  :plain
    if(someCondition()) {
      doSomething();
    }
```

produces:

```html
<script data-turbolinks-eval='false' foo='bar'>
  if(someCondition()) {
    doSomething();
  }
</script>
```