# Can I add an attribute to a filter in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, premailer

I'm using premailer-rails gem for a newsletter e-mail which is responsive. The gem is removing media queries that are within my `.scss` file by default. Premailer comes with an option that works only on style tags `data_premailer => ignore`, which leaves the style tag untouched.

I'd like to set this attribute while using the :scss filter in haml:

```
:scss // <- can I add an attribute here?
```

I went through the haml docs with no success, I also tried:

```
 :scss, data_premailer: "ignore"
 :scss{ data_premailer: "ignore" }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450524/specify-options-for-a-filter-in-ruby-haml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify options for a filter in ruby HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450524/specify-options-for-a-filter-in-ruby-haml)

Answer (score 1):

You use plain filter inside css

```
%style{"data-premailer" => "ignore"}
  :plain
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    }
```